# How to replace preprocessor macro with if statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement, c-preprocessor

Usually, the preprocessor macro is used to control some code group to be compiled or not. Here is one example.

```
#define ENABLE 1

void testswitch(int type){

    switch(type){
    case 1:
        std::cout << "the value is 1" << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        std::cout << "the value is 2" << endl;
        break;
#ifdef ENABLE
    case 3:
        std::cout << "the value is 3" << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        std::cout << "the value is 4" << endl;
    }
#endif
    }
}
```

Now I want to remove all those preprocessor macros and replace them with `if` condition

```
void testswitch(int type, bool enable){
    switch(type){
    case 1:
        std::cout << "the value is 1" << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        std::cout << "the value is 2" << endl;
        break;
    if (enable) {
    case 3:
        std::cout << "the value is 3" << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        std::cout << "the value is 4" << endl;
    }
    }
}
```

However, the above codes doesn't have the same logic as before. No matter the variable `enable` is `true` or `false`, the `case 3` and `case 4` are always enable. Those codes are test under VS2010.

**Q1: Does the compiler ignore the `if` condition?**

To achieve my goal, I have to change those codes as following:

```
void testswitch(int type, bool enable){
    switch(type){
    case 1:
        std::cout << "the value is 1" << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        std::cout << "the value is 2" << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        if (enable) 
            std::cout << "the value is 3" << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        if (enable) 
            std::cout << "the value is 4" << endl;
    }
}
```

But it seems there are redundant `if` in the codes. **Is there any better way to do that?**

Comment: 1st syntax is simply wrong. 2nd way is questionable as being advised instead of having a `#ifdef`, the results are very different.

Comment: Since the syntax is wrong in 1st, why the codes can be built successfully in VS? May I considerate this is one bug in VS2010?

Comment: @zangw The syntax is not wrong in the sense of "this is a syntax error," but in the sense of "it doesn't do even remotely what you want."

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The first syntax is fully legal (although I would consider it wrong morally).  The semantics of `switch` are quite close to those of `goto`: if `type` is 3, the code "goes to" the label `case 3`.  (Which explains why his first example doesn't work; the goto jumps over the `if`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler does not ignore the `if` condition. But you have to bear in mind that the `case` labels are *labels.* `switch` is just a more organised approach to `goto`. Since `goto` can jump into blocks controlled by an `if` (or a loop, or any others) just fine, so can a `switch`.

You could put the `enable`-only cases in a separate switch:

```
void testswitch(int type, bool enable) {
  switch(type) {
  case 1:
    std::cout << "the value is 1" << endl;
    break;
  case 2:
    std::cout << "the value is 2" << endl;
    break;
  default:
    if (enable) {
      switch(type) {
      case 3:
        std::cout << "the value is 3" << endl;
        break;
      case 4:
        std::cout << "the value is 4" << endl;
        break;
      }
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1: you solution is similar to mine, but more efficient.

Comment: @PaulR Yeah, I took some inspiration from your solution and just advanced it a bit, so I gave you an upvote to compensate :-)

Comment: The key is the analogy to `goto`.  And there are actually a few (very rare) cases where this is useful (for reasons other than obfuscation).

Answer (score 1):

One other solution is to refactor this into two `switch` statements, with the second one being controlled by `if (enable)`:

```
void testswitch(int type, bool enable) {
    switch(type) {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "the value is 1" << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "the value is 2" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (enable) {
        switch(type) {
            case 3:
                std::cout << "the value is 3" << endl;
                break;
            case 4:
                std::cout << "the value is 4" << endl;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `enable` is a constant (or otherwise known at compile-time), a reasonably smart compiler (like gcc) will not generate code to check the value of `enable`, but will generate no code (if it is known to be false) or generate the then-statement otherwise.